# How to add a SCSI disk to share between two Server 2012 in Vmware?

Tags: esxi, scsi, vsphere

I'm trying to add a second disk as SCSI to Windows Server 2012. This disk has to be accessible to another Server 2012 for some load-balancing purposes. How do I create such second disk and share it between two VMs?

edit: This is what I tried step by step: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/77764-add-share-disks-for-ms-clustering-on-vmware
Everything went well however Servers doesn't see same data.

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided is the proper way to share a SCSI disk in ESXi. I can only assume you're using the NTFS file system which doesn't support multiple systems access the same disk at the same time, outside of special use cases such as Failover Clustering. And even then on my Windows Server 2016 file server fail over cluster, I cannot access the disk from the secondary node. It would help if you were to say why you are trying to do this.

[image: diskpart screenshot]

Comment: It's necessary for some development environment. I have solved this issue by using a third party software called Starwind

Comment: IIRC with windows you can also bring the disk online on both systems at the same time with the diskpart command, but please be aware that the FAT32, NTFS and ReFS file systems do not support this and you will eventually experience data corruption, even if you do so over iSCSI using Starwind as the target. If you're using the NFS or SMB file sharing features of Starwind then you'll be fine, but in that circumstance you would not be exposing a SCSI disk/block storage device to the computers.

Comment: Much obliged sir thank you for the headsup. I've been using ntfs with Starwind.

Comment: You should look in to using CSVFS instead

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612868(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: CSVFS should be layered on top of the shared storage, it doesn't exist by itself.

Comment: I've had a similar concern a while ago. CSVFS is, basically, an abstraction layer on top of NTFS. And yes, you should indeed use CSVFS in order to allow the simoultaneous multiple access to your shared storage. Check out the page 31 of this guidance: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-hyper-converged-2-nodes-scenario-2-nodes-with-hyper-v-cluster